# What is the equivalent of Android's Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP) in Java

Tags: java, base64

I have looked for this information on stackoverflow but I can't find the exact answer I want.

If we use Java's version of `Base64` in `java.util`, what is Java's equivalent of Android's `Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP)` in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've identified correctly that you need [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html). If you read its documentation, you'd see that it supports three types of Base 64 en/decoding. Since the Android code you are trying to translate says `NO_WRAP`, you should use either the basic encoder or the URL encoder, both of which do not wrap lines. The MIME decoder *does* wrap lines, which is not what you want.

```
Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder(); // for the basic encoder, or:
// Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getUrlEncoder(); for the URL encoder
```

On `Base64.Encoder`, you'll see a method with exactly the same name as the android method - `encodeToString`.

```
String encoded = encoder.encodeToString(data);
```